# AdMob banner does not showing on Android M

Tags: android, admob, google-dfp

I'm using Google AdMob SDK for display DFP banners, but it only worked on Android < 6.0.

On 6.0+ devices I got this error :

```
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Even with the sample project provided by Google I encounter the exact same error message.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/doubleclick/BannerExample

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**

This is my gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

Comment: update Androd Support Library and also new API. Update all things  and this start˙s to work

Comment: @siddhesh, thanks for your advice, but I'm not sure how to do that ?

Comment: from your gradle check your dependencies whether they are updated

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've solve this problem by simply remove all Play Service updates so that it back to `9.4.0`, and everything works again.

I've also tried to upgrade Play Service back to `10.0.84` as well, and the problem just gone, not knowing why but it indeed solve the problem.